# Lorentz contraction and Planck length and time

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

Given the definition of the Planck length

$$ \ell_\mathrm{P} =\sqrt\frac{\hbar G}{c^3} \ $$

and the Planck time

$$ T_{P}\equiv \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^5}}, $$

if we take into account an observer moving with respect to us with speed $v$, then due to Lorentz contraction Planck length and time would be different for different observers. How to explain this with special relativity?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4094/50583

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369532/

Answer (score 1):

These values are simply defined values that qualitatively express the limits of the theory.

They're not the real lengths of physical objects so contraction does not affect these values.

Comment: The second sentence is correct, the first only debatably so. While it is *conjectured* that some of the Planck units represent such limits, in no currently unequivocally accepted theory could we *definitely* deduce that the Planck units have any real physical significance. E.g. the Planck mass is around 21 µg and has certainly no special significance within current QFT or GR.

Comment: My understanding is that it is generally accepted that current mainstream theories are not reliable below the Plank length, hence my use of the word "qualitatively".

Comment: Perhaps you can replace "qualitatively" with "hypothetically."