# Can the Planck length be altered by relativistic motion?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, physical-constants

If a spaceship is flying by you at high speed relative to you, will the [Planck length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) in the moving frame be smaller than the planck length in the non-moving frame.  Will observers in the different frames disagree about the planck length due to length contraction?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_special_relativity

Comment: depend how u measure e.g. train and the tunnel of equal length can be measured with our eye so you must get the drift ;D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Planck length at relativistic speeds?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369532/)

Comment: @JohnRennie  Maybe I will post another question. This was somewhat of a leading question since I assumed there would be a difference, but my real question was probably headed toward, this "since the planck length can be expressed in terms of h, c G, (and perhaps pi) wouldn't one of those constants have to change, and how would you decide which one?

Answer (score 0):

In standard relativity the Planck length is just another unit. It contracts just as the meter and the mile do.

Perhaps a future theory of quantum gravity will say something different.