# Is the Planck length frame dependent?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, physical-constants

In accordance with special relativity, if we take into account length contraction then ideally the Planck length which is the smallest possible length possible should be frame dependent. Well we know that the number of particles are invariant in different frames. So, a frame travelling with some relative velocity will see the same number of particles but their length contracted by a factor. According to this logic, the Planck length should change with different frames. Yet it is defined by using the fundamental constants G,c and h which obviously do not change with frame. This could only imply two things :-

1. One of the fundamental constants G,c,h are frame dependent (which I do not believe could be since they are fundamental constants)
2. The shortest possible length cannot be written only in terms of fundamental constants

The second conclusion seems more apt but is it right or is there something more to this?

Comment: First, why is the Planck length the smallest possible length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Planck length Lorentz invariant?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4094/)

Comment: One solution would be that between two points, the number of Planck lengths separating them depends on the referential, while the Planck length never changes. This is inspired by the relativity of the concept of "number of particles" in QFT in Curved Space-Time.

Answer (score 2):

This falls in the realm of quantum gravity where we no longer know the answer (because there is no widely-accepted theory of quantum gravity). A Planck length that is frame-independent would violate special relativity, but it is argued that the Planck length has to be frame-independent, or the Principle of Relativity would be violated (i.e. different observers see different laws of physics).

There's a whole theory built on the idea that the Planck length is frame-independent, called [Doubly Special Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_special_relativity). I'm no expert on this theory, but if the Wikipedia article is correct, it is not observationally excluded - but it is also not observationally supported, so far.